# Android. Replace a character with a character from numeric character reference

Tags: android, xml

I often read such messages. But what is the reason of the replacement? I only know that a space bar cannot be at the end of a string because it will be ignored and you will get the string without the space bar.

```
<string name="lorem">Lorem and a space bar&#160;</string>
```

But what about everything else? I don't see any visual difference between

```
<string name="loading">Loading&#8230;</string>
```

and

```
<string name="loading">Loading...</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this answer. This is just to use less characters if possible and there is no point making three dots if the appropriate character is available for this. It's good to use Unicode value in this case. You can also tell [Lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint) to ignore this if you with.

[Android Replace "..." with ellipsis character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536375/android-replace-with-ellipsis-character)