# What is the Eclipse code to use instead of dot on Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to use a string like this:

```
<string name="deleting">Deleting...</string>
```

I don't know what is the code which should i use instead of `...`

Also, does that answer would be different if i choosed another language than english ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536375/android-replace-with-ellipsis-character/8536464#8536464. check this.

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for your comment. that works, does the answer changes with another languages ?

Comment: why would it change? no i don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&#8230;` is the unicode for `…` so replace `Deleting...` by `&#8230;`.

```
<string name="deleting">Deleting&#8230;</string>
```

Credits to warren faith source @

[Android Replace "..." with ellipsis character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536375/android-replace-with-ellipsis-character/8536464#8536464)

You can use `...`. The lint will warn you about it (Replace "..." with ellipsis character (..., …) ). You can disable Lint warning. I would not disable lint warning because i feel its useful.

Go to Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking
And search for "ellipsis". Change the warning level to "Info" or "Ignore".

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use ANY value between

```
<string name="deleting">Blank$***_ - ()!@#45 </string>
```

this tag ....
Use and Enjoy Android Development..

best wish to you,

Answer (score 0):

i hope it's help just replace **...** with `&#x2026;`