# Why gradle lint think ellipsis character "&#8230;" is more readable than "..."?

Tags: android, gradle, lint

I define a string "XXX..." in string.xml and get a gradle lint issue.

```
Replace "..." with ellipsis character (…, &#8230;) ?
Explanation: Ellipsis string can be replaced with ellipsis character.
You can replace the string "..." with a dedicated ellipsis character,
ellipsis character (…, &#8230;). This can help make the text more readable.
```

Why is "…" more readable than "..."? When someone see "&#8230", I don't think he/she can realize that this is a ellipsis character.

Comment: It doesn't mean readable for other people - it means readable for other programs that are going to have to display the text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's about good typography. The [actual ellipsis character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm) is almost always preferred to the approximation of having three dots. In some fonts, three dots in a row just have too much space in between while the actual ellipsis character looks nice: the font designer can control the appearance of the dedicated ellipsis sign but he can't control how three dots in a row should be displayed.

It's like using an em-dash "–" vs. the approximation with two minus-signs "--": using an approximation by combining several normal characters instead of using the dedicated character almost always looks clumsy and unprofessional.