# Android replace ... with &#8230;

Tags: android

I'm getting this warning:
Replace "..." with ellipsis character (..., '&#8230';) ?
in my strings.xml
at this line:

```
string name="scanning">Scanning... string>
```

If someone could help me please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Replace "..." with ellipsis character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536375/android-replace-with-ellipsis-character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&#8230;` means `...`

Instead of `Scanning...` you need `Scanning&#8230;`in that string Resource.

Answer (score 2):

It suggests you to replace the three '.' characters to a single '...' character.

Comment: how to write '...' as a single character

Answer (score 0):

Replace your string

```
<string name="scanning">Scanning... </string>
```

With this string

```
<string name="scanning">Scanning&#8230;</string>
```